# How use java 8 in Android api 21?

Tags: java, android

Android studio 3.2, Android api 21., java 1.8

In my **app/build.gradle**:

```
compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

I want to use new features of Java 8, like try-with-resources, streams and so on.
But it require at least api 24. What can I do?

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: Try with resources are available in any version of Android, so long as you use a higher version build tool to compile with (and the minimum version of that which the play store currently accepts is 26).  Streams absolutely require v24-  the classes don't exist in pre-24 SDKs.  You could try to find open source implementations of those classes and use those instead.  But you're better off avoiding them or using libraries (like RxJava for streams).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments by @leonardkraemer and @gabe-sechan cover most of the topic.

For most of the features you pretty much just have to use desugaring and Android Studio 3+. After you set java version, like shown below, Android Studio will start suggesting Java 8 things in your code.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Streams are not a language feature, but a library, so there's a good port of it: https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API. This library covers `java.util.stream` and `java.util.function`.